# Modelo de Requisição SOAP E-SOcial

Tags: php, api

Fala, pessoal, estou com sérios problemas pra executar a requisição SOAP nos servidores do e-social.

Esse é o meu código:

```
    $pfx = file_get_contents($pfx);
    $certificate = Certificate::readPfx($pfx, $pass);

    $wsdl = 'https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc?WSDL';
    $arquivo_xml = file_get_contents(ROOT_APP_CONTROLLER."rh/esocial/teste.xml");

    $action = 'EnviarLoteEventos';
    $operation = '';
    $parameters = [];
    $namespaces = [];
    $request = htmlentities($arquivo_xml, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    $soapheader = null;

    try {
        $soap = new \NFePHP\Common\Soap\SoapCurl($certificate);
        $response = $soap->send($wsdl, $operation, $action, SOAP_1_1, $parameters, $namespaces, $request, $soapheader);
        print_r($response);     

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print_r($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Ele me apresenta o seguinte erro no retorno do try catch:

```
An error occurred while trying to communication via soap,  [https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc?WSDL]HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8;action=EnviarLoteEventos' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=kfr2yuodygwpey5lnoronfzi; path=/; HttpOnly
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 27 Apr 2018 12:15:18 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Ai eu imaginei que seria somente eu alterar o cabeçalho da requição para text/xml; charset=utf-8', porém, quando eu mudo, ele me apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
An error occurred while trying to communication via soap,  [https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc?WSDL]HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=k0ii5ocr23zuujcgcuw0xfl2; path=/; HttpOnly
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 27 Apr 2018 12:18:40 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Já estou a 3 dias batendo cabeça nisso, se alguém souber como resolver, me ajude por favor!!!

Answer (score 0):

A mensagem é bem clara, você está enviando um *Content-type* inválido, diferente do que o serviço está esperando.

Tente adicionar o *Content-type*  correto no header da requisição, algo assim:

```
$soapheader = array("Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8",
                    "Accept: text/xml");
```